# How to install ttyd from source on Fedora?

Tags: fedora, shared-library, cmake

I'm trying to compile [`ttyd`](https://github.com/tsl0922/ttyd) that requires [`libwebsockets`](https://github.com/warmcat/libwebsockets) on Fedora. My system has an outdated version of `ttyd` and I need a newer one to run [vhs tool](https://github.com/charmbracelet/vhs).

Both projects use CMake, I was able to compile and install both.

When I run `ttyd` from the build directory it works fine. But when I run from somewhere else I've got this error:

```
ttyd: error while loading shared libraries: libwebsockets.so.19: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

When I added build directory to my `PATH` variable I can use `ttyd` and `vhs` but I would like to have proper installation of `ttyd` that just works. What I did wrong?

Note that I've installed `ttyd` and `libwebsockets` but then remove them.

I can probably care symlink for a shared library, but this is not an actual fix to the problem. Why the shared library is missing if I installed both from source?

**EDIT**:

I've installed both packages the same way:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
sudo make install
```

Shared library got installed in `/usr/local/lib/`

Comment: Can you update this question to show the exact steps you followed to build and install the binaries and shared libraries? Where did the shared library get installed?

Comment: @larsks I used default way to install from cmake. `mkdir build && cd build && cmake .. && make && sudo make install` I didn't pick any place to install the library. The shared library got installed in `/usr/local/lib/` I didn't change the default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `/usr/local/lib` isn't included in the default shared library search path. There are three ways to resolve this:

1. Set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` before running `ttyd`:

   ```
   $ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib ttyd
   ```
2. Update the default library search path:

   ```
   # echo /usr/local/lib > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/local.conf
   # ldconfig
   ```
3. Compile the library path into the binary when you build it:

   ```
   $ cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH=/usr/local/lib ..
   ```

Any of the above three options will allow `ttyd` to locate the `libwebsockets` shared library.